# Javascript multiple choice questionnaire. How do I change the Code so its possible to tick more than one answer? (with the 8th one)

Tags: javascript, web

This is my Code for my Quiz. 
I tried to change it somehow but it still doesnt let me choose more than one option. 
Do i need an extra Code or do i have to change the whole thing? Also if anyone can see any errors, please say so. 
Thank You in Advance :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Knowledge Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style folder/styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var numQuest=8
            var ie=document.all
            function showAnswer(el,ans){
            ie? ie[el].innerHTML='The answer is: '+ ans : document.getElementById(el).innerHTML='The answer is: '+ ans
            }

            function addup()  {
            var q, right, statement, total=0
            questions=new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < numQuest; i++)
            questions[i]=0
            if (document.forms.quiz.q1['right1']){
            for (i = 0; i < numQuest; i++){
            q="q"+(i+1)
            right="right"+(i+1)
            if (document.forms.quiz[q][right].checked)
            questions[i]=1
            }
            }
            else if (document.getElementById){
            for (i = 0; i < numQuest; i++){
            right="right"+(i+1)
            if (document.getElementById(right).checked)
            questions[i]=1
            }
            }
            else
            return;
            for (i = 0; i < numQuest; i++)
            total += questions[i]
            /*///////////Set score /////////////*/
            statement='You scored '+ total +' out of '+ numQuest +' correct, '+ Math.round(total/numQuest*100) +'%'
            ie? ie.results.innerHTML=statement : document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=statement
            }
            function clearR(){
            ie? ie.results.innerHTML='' : document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=''
            for (i = 0; i < numQuest; i++)
            ie? ie["ans"+(i+1)].innerHTML='' : document.getElementById("ans"+(i+1)).innerHTML=''
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <header>
                <div class="width">
                    <h1>Quiz</h1>

                    <nav>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usability.html">Usability</a></li>
                            <li><a href="additional information.html">Additional Information</a></li>
                            <li><a href="how i built this website.html">How I built this Website</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
                        </ul>   

                    </nav>

                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="body" class="width">
                <center><h1>Test your Knowledge</h1></center>

                <hr>
                <form name="quiz">

                    Question 1:<br>
                    Which HTML attribute is used to define an inline style sheet?<br>
                    <input id="w1a" type="radio" unchecked name="q1"><label for="w1a">class</label><br>
                    <input id="right1" type="radio" unchecked name="q1"><label for="right1">style</label><br>
                    <input id="w1b" type="radio" unchecked name="q1"><label for="w1b">in-style</label><br>
                    <input id="w1c" type="radio" unchecked name="q1"><label for="w1c">font</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans1','style')">&nbsp;<span id="ans1" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 2:<br>
                    What is the correct CSS syntax for making all the <"p"> elements bold?<br>
                    <input id="w2a" type="radio" unchecked name="q2"><label for="w2a">p style="text-size:bold"</label><br>
                    <input id="w2b" type="radio" unchecked name="q2"><label for="w2b">p {text-size:bold}</label><br>
                    <input id="right2" type="radio" unchecked name="q2"><label for="right2">p{font-weight:bold}</label><br>
                    <input id="w2c" type="radio" unchecked name="q2"><label for="w2c">p style="font-size:bold"</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans2','p{font-weight:bold}')">&nbsp;<span id="ans2" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 3:<br>
                    What does HTML stand for?<br>
                    <input id="w3a" type="radio" unchecked name="q3"><label for="w3a">Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language</label><br>
                    <input id="w3b" type="radio" unchecked name="q3"><label for="w3b">Home Tool Markup Language</label><br>
                    <input id="right3" type="radio" unchecked name="q3"><label for="right3">Hyper Text Markup Laguage</label><br>
                    <input id="w3c" type="radio" unchecked name="q3"><label for="w3c">High Technic Markup Language</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans3','Hyper Text Markup Laguage')">&nbsp;<span id="ans3" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 4:<br>
                    What does CSS stand for?<br>
                    <input id="right4" type="radio" unchecked name="q4"><label for="right4">Cascading Style Sheets</label><br>
                    <input id="w4a" type="radio" unchecked name="q4"><label for="w4a">Creative Style Sheets</label><br>
                    <input id="w4b" type="radio" unchecked name="q4"><label for="w4b">Computer Style Sheets</label><br>
                    <input id="w4c" type="radio" unchecked name="q4"><label for="w4c">Colorful Style Sheets</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans4','Cascading Style Sheets')">&nbsp;<span id="ans4" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 5:<br>
                    Choose the right text color for a Website with a white background.<br>
                    <input id="right5" type="radio" unchecked name="q5"><label for="right5">black</label><br>
                    <input id="w5a" type="radio" unchecked name="q5"><label for="w5a">orange</label><br>
                    <input id="w5b" type="radio" unchecked name="q5"><label for="w5b">red</label><br>
                    <input id="w5c" type="radio" unchecked name="q5"><label for="w5c">yellow</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans5','black')">&nbsp;<span id="ans5" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 6:<br>
                    Where in an HTML document is the correct place to refer to an external style sheet?<br>
                    <input id="w6a" type="radio" unchecked name="q6"><label for="w6a">In the <"head"> section</label><br>
                    <input id="w6b" type="radio" unchecked name="q6"><label for="w6b">At the end of the document</label><br>
                    <input id="right6" type="radio" unchecked name="q6"><label for="right6">At the top of the document</label><br>
                    <input id="w6c" type="radio" unchecked name="q6"><label for="w6c">In the <"body"> section</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans6','black')">&nbsp;<span id="ans6" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 7:<br>
                    Which property is used to change the background color?<br>
                    <input id="w7a" type="radio" unchecked name="q7"><label for="w7a">color</label><br>
                    <input id="right7" type="radio" unchecked name="q7"><label for="right7">background-color</label><br>
                    <input id="w7b" type="radio" unchecked name="q7"><label for="w7b">bgcolor</label><br>
                    <input id="w7c" type="radio" unchecked name="q7"><label for="w7c">bgc</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans7','black')">&nbsp;<span id="ans7" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    Question 8:<br>
                    On a web page, how and where should be the logo/brand name?(choose 2)<br>
                    <input id="right8" type="radio" unchecked name="q8"><label for="right8">easy</label><br>
                    <input id="right8" type="radio" unchecked name="q8"><label for="right8">upper-left corner of the screen</label><br>
                    <input id="w8a" type="radio" unchecked name="q8"><label for="w8a">in the middle of the screen</label><br>
                    <input id="w8b" type="radio" unchecked name="q8"><label for="w8b">hard</label><br>
                    <input class="chkans" type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="showAnswer('ans8','easy','upper-left corner of the screen')">&nbsp;<span id="ans8" class="chkans"></span>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>
                    <!--End of Questions-->
                    <hr><br>
                    <input type="button" value="See Score" onclick="addup()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="results"></span><br>&nbsp;<br>
                    <input type="button" value="Start Again" onclick="reset();clearR()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<input type="checkbox">` instead of `<input type="radio">`.

[input type="radio"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html)  represents a selection of one item from a list of items

[input type="checkbox"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html) represents a state or option that can be toggled

Comment: Hey thanks! It works! But i have one last problem. When i check the answer it still shows only the one answer. How can i change it so it shows two answers?

Comment: It doesnt matter anymore, i got it :)

Comment: you want to count each item in 8th question? For example, you can specify different id's for each item (equal identifiers are not allowed). just change id attribute of the last input to `right9`  and set `numQuest` to `9`. [http://jsfiddle.net/orfko96v/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/orfko96v/1/)